# cross compiling rpm source code for arm

Tags: c, linux, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm trying to run autoconf to generate the Makefile necessary to cross compile the rpm code for arm-based Zynq board.

When I run:

```
./configure --host=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/nspr -I/usr/include/nss -I/usr/include/linux"
```

I get the following error:

```
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C99... unsupported
configure: error: ISO C99 capable compiler required
```

Comment: 1) The message is very clear. 2) See [ask]

Comment: There's either a `c99` flag you need to set (like: `-std=c99` in your configure script), or you need to use another cross-compiler that supports C99.

Comment: thanks SnakeDoc!  I tried setting it with the CFLAGS -std=c99 earlier and it did not work but when I switched to -std=C99 it got through to another error.